# ffmpeg audio synch issue - fractional framerate

Tags: android, c, ffmpeg, frame-rate

We are working on an Android app which uses the ffmpeg library via JNI to edit the frames of a video while keeping size, codec etc the same.

We are having an issue where the audio of the output video is getting out of sync with the video. We believe this is because some input videos have a frame rate which isn't a whole number e.g 25.66 fps and our output will be at 25fps. We have tried to change the time_base field of the output codec to keep the precision i.e by multiply the numerator and denominator but it makes the output frame rate ridiculously high.

Does anyone know how to force ffmpeg to use the exact same output frame rate as the one it reads in? We have not found a way to output videos with a fractional frame rate.

Example of setting up the output codec:

```
    c =                 st->codec;
    c->codec_id =       codec_id;
    c->codec_type =     AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    c->bit_rate =       inputCodecCtx->bit_rate;
    c->width =          inputCodecCtx->width;
    c->height =         inputCodecCtx->height;

    c->time_base.num =   1000;
    c->time_base.den =  (int)(fps*1000);//fps of the input video *1000 to keep precision

    c->gop_size =       inputCodecCtx->gop_size;
    c->pix_fmt =        inputCodecCtx->pix_fmt;



    static int write_video_frame(AVFormatContext *oc, AVStream *st, AVFrame *newpict, double fps)
    {
        int             ret = 0;
        AVCodecContext* c = st->codec;

        AVPacket pkt;
        av_init_packet(&pkt);

        if (pkt.pts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)
        {
            pkt.pts =  av_rescale_q(c->coded_frame->pts, c->time_base, st->time_base);

        }
        if (pkt.dts != AV_NOPTS_VALUE)


        {
            pkt.dts = av_rescale_q(c->coded_frame->pts, c->time_base, st->time_base);
        }

.....
}
```

Comment: Are you appropriately setting the packet pts and dts values to match the unit of time in the codec?

Comment: I believe we are, I've added that part to the question text